# Visualize a binary vector

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a binary column in pandas dataframe. I want to visualize it, just to see how much there is `0` or `1`. I used `displot`:

```
Plot = sns.displot(data = data, x = 'stroke', color = 'm')
Plot.fig.suptitle('Stroke numbers in data', size=15, y=1.12);
```

This did the job but it's very ugly, how do I make it only with 0 and 1 ?:

[image]

Comment: You could try `discrete=True` as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good solution:

```
data["stroke"].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(rot=0)
```